# Xamarin iOS Deployment failes silently

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have recently upgraded to VS 15.5.1 and suddenly I cannot deploy on iOS anymore. There is nothing in the standard output only in the Xamarin log files I could find a stack trace:

> Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MonoTouchFlavoredProject|Error|0|An error occurred while lauching Application for debugging
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Xamarin.MacDev.ManifestExtensions.GetCFBundleIdentifier(PDictionary dict) in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\External\Xamarin.MacDev\Xamarin.MacDev\ManifestExtensions.cs:line 119
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MonoTouchFlavoredProject.GetRunSessionInfo(MonoTouchDevice device) in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.IOS\ProjectSystem\MonoTouchFlavoredProject.cs:line 1035
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MonoTouchFlavoredProject.CreateDebuggerStartInfo(MonoTouchDevice device, Int32 debugPort) in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.IOS\ProjectSystem\MonoTouchFlavoredProject.cs:line 907
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MonoTouchFlavoredProject.StartDebugging(MonoTouchDevice device, IProgressReport progress, MonoDebuggerLauncher debug_session) in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.IOS\ProjectSystem\MonoTouchFlavoredProject.cs:line 980
>      at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MonoTouchFlavoredProject.<>c__DisplayClass75_0.b__0() in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.IOS\ProjectSystem\MonoTouchFlavoredProject.cs:line 955

This applies to simmulator and device deployments. It seems like it fails to retrieve the BundleIdentifier from the plist, but it is there and deploying worked just fine with the last VS version.
Does somebody have a clue?

Comment: Try to delete the bin and obj folder, clean , rebuild.

Comment: already tried that a few times. Unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: whenever we get this kind of silent fails we definitely have something messed up in our views

Comment: but in our case the app worked before the VS upgrade. The solution for me is listed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had a problem in our iOS .proj file because we had different .plist files for dev and release:

```
<None Include="Info_debug.plist" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">   <SubType>Designer</SubType>   <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName> </None> <None Include="Info_release.plist" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">   <SubType>Designer</SubType>   <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName> </None>
```

somehow either the logicalname property does not work anymore or the Condition makes some trouble, so we hotfixed it to the following:

```
<None Include="Info.plist" />
```

Now it works again...